# 404 Error on Stripe Webhook in Node

Tags: node.js, https, stripe-payments, webhooks, stripe.js

I have the following code setup for a webhook:

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var nodemailer = require('nodemailer');
var middleware = require('../middleware');
var stripe = require("stripe")(process.env.SECRET_KEY);

// router.use(require("body-parser").raw({type: "*/*"}));

router.post("/webhook/all", function(req, res) {
  // Retrieve the request's body and parse it as JSON
  // var event_json = JSON.parse(req.body);
  middleware.sendEmail('Webhook Test', 'event_json');
  res.sendStatus(200);
});

module.exports = router;
```

When I test this with `localhost` and Postman it works, however when it is live it responds with a 404 error:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Error</title>
</head>
<body>
<pre>Cannot POST /webhook/all</pre>
</body>
</html>
```

My only guess is it has something to do with my `HTTPS`, since the [Stripe Docs](https://stripe.com/docs/webhooks) say this:

> If you use an HTTPS URL for your webhook endpoint, Stripe will
>   validate that the connection to your server is secure before sending
>   your webhook data. For this to work, your server must be correctly
>   configured to support HTTPS with a valid server certificate.

My SSL certificate is setup with Let's Encrypt on a DO droplet, and it seems to be working fine, so I'm not sure why this would be the issue though.

**Note**: I purposefully made `event_json` a string, since I am trying to remove as many possible confounding variables as possible. Once this works as a string I will uncomment `body-parser` and switch `event_json` over to a variable again.

Answer (score 1):

You need to tunnel your localhost to public. Please use [ngrok](https://ngrok.com/) for this. It will **generate a random public url for your localhost application** every time you run `ngrok`

Suppose your localhost URL is `http://localhost:3000/webhook/all`, the ngrok url will be like `https://somerandomurl/webhook/all`.

Then you can this public url to receive all the webhook events on localhost.

PS: When you will hit CTRL+C on ngrok it will stop the tunneling and your application will no longer be able to receive any webhook event. Also you will get higher failure rates on the stripe